# Simple Command system

Tags: c#

Below I have coded a simple command system that passes a string to a method and checks if the first word split by (' ') is a key in the registered commands dictionary, if it is, it executes the class that is stored as the dictionary entry's value.

few examles of what is typed for commands

```
@mycommand hello
:ohnicecommand John
.setamount 10000
```

CommandHandler.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Sirius.Base.Game.Habbo.Commands
{
    using Commands;
    using Commands.Habbo;
    using Other.GameClients;

    internal class CommandHandler
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, ICommand> _commandsRegistered;

        internal CommandHandler()
        {
            _commandsRegistered = new Dictionary<string, ICommand>();

            RegisterCommands();
        }

        private void RegisterCommands()
        {
            RegisterCommand(":info", new InfoCommand());
        }

        public bool IsCommandInput(Player player, string input)
        {
            ICommand command;

            var cmdString = input.Split(' ')[0];

            if (!_commandsRegistered.TryGetValue(cmdString, out command))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (command.PermissionRequired != "" && !player.GetPlayerData().GetPermissions().HasCommand(command.PermissionRequired))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (command.NumberOfParameters < input.Split(' ').Length)
            {
                player.SendWhisper("Invalid command syntax -- " + cmdString + " " + command.CommandParameters);
                return true;
            }

            DateTime lastExecuted;

            if (player.GetPlayerData()._commandCooldowns.TryGetValue(cmdString, out lastExecuted))
            {
                var commandSpan = DateTime.Now - lastExecuted;

                if (command.CommandCooldown && commandSpan.TotalSeconds < (command.CommandCooldownMs / 1000))
                {
                    player.SendNotification("You're cooling down from this command! [" + commandSpan.TotalSeconds + "/" + (command.CommandCooldownMs / 1000) + "]");
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                player.GetPlayerData()._commandCooldowns.Add(cmdString, DateTime.Now);
            }

            command.ProcessCommand(player);

            return true;
        }

        private void RegisterCommand(string commandName, ICommand command)
        {
            _commandsRegistered.Add(commandName, command);
        }
    }
}
```

ICommand:

```
namespace Sirius.Base.Game.Habbo.Commands.Commands
{
    using Other.GameClients;

    internal interface ICommand
    {
        void ProcessCommand(Player player);
        string PermissionRequired { get; }
        int NumberOfParameters { get; }
        string CommandParameters { get; }
        string CommandDescription { get; }
        bool CommandCooldown { get; }
        int CommandCooldownMs { get; }
    }
}
```

InfoCommand (just 1 of many commands)

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace Sirius.Base.Game.Habbo.Commands.Commands.Habbo
{
    using Other.Communication.Packets.Outgoing.Notifications;
    using Other.GameClients;

    internal sealed class InfoCommand : ICommand
    {
        public string PermissionRequired => "";
        public int NumberOfParameters => 0;
        public string CommandParameters => "";
        public string CommandDescription => "Lets you view information about the server.";
        public bool CommandCooldown => true;
        public int CommandCooldownMs => 5000;

        public void ProcessCommand(Player player)
        {
            // do what ever you want the command to do here...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should, at the very least, include the body of `ProcessCommand` for the `InfoCommand` to help reviewers find more potential for optimization.

Comment: Also, what does a command with `CommandParameters` set look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The biggest issue I see is you have to *manually* register **each and every** command. Why bother? Why not just get a list of all commands that implement `ICommand` through Reflection? Speed shouldn't be a *huge* problem because I assume you do this on some sort of start-up.

```
var baseCommandInterface = typeof(ICommand);
var commands = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(p => baseCommandInterface.IsAssignableFrom(p));
```

Now just enumerate `commands` and cast and operate on them. Life should be a lot easier this way.

---

Next, why bother with a `bool` *and* `int` for cool downs? Just use an `int?`, if it's `null` then there's no cool down, if its `>0` then that's the cool down time. Pretty simple.

---

You use the term `Command` *way* too many times for my tastes.

```
internal interface ICommand
{
    void Process(Player player);
    string PermissionRequired { get; }
    int NumberOfParameters { get; }
    string Parameters { get; }
    string Description { get; }
    int? CooldownMs { get; }
}
```

Even then, `NumberOfParameters` is *truly* unnecessary. I'd bet there is a separator of some sort between commands in the `Parameters` string, which really shouldn't be a string, but should be something like the following:

```
public class CommandParameter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then `Parameters` becomes an `IEnumerable<CommandParameter>` which means you can use `Parameters.Count` in place of `NumberOfParameters`. This *also* means you can extrapolate further and define an abstract class for this, and add a `CanProcess(Player player)` method:

```
public abstract class BaseCommand : ICommand
{
    private List<CommandParameter> _parameters = new List<CommandParameter>();
    public IEnumerable<CommandParameter> Parameters => _parameters;

    public int? Cooldown { get; protected set; }
    public string Description { get; protected set; }
    public string PermissionRequired { get; protected set; }

    public abstract void ProcessCommand(Player player);

    public bool CanProcess(Player player)
    {
        // Check cool down, permissions, ban list, etc.
    }
}
```

Then in an actual command:

```
public class InfoCommand : BaseCommand
{
    public InfoCommand()
    {
        Cooldown = 5000;
        Description = "Lets you view information about the server.";
    }

    public override void ProcessCommand(Player player)
    {
        if (!CanProcess(player))
        {
            // I'm throwing an exception, but you could just `return` and send a message or whatever
            throw new InvalidOperationException("You have either exceeded the cool down, do not have permissions, or are banned. Please try again later.");
        }

        // Process our command here
    }
}
```

Then you created your own system that requires boilerplate code, **and** extracted that boilerplate code away.

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure what you mean by your first comment about loading the commands, where do I put the custom input that triggers each individual command?

Comment: @Ashkru Give each command a `Trigger` property that is the `:info` thing or whatever.

Comment: @Ashkru Is this the answer? I've noticed that you ask a lot of questions yet never choose to pick a selected answer.